# SQl aggregation across 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table-1 as

```
        id       date      no.of times
        1122   2020-03-29     5
        1122   2020-03-25     3
        1122   2020-03-27     1
        2233   2020-03-29    10
        2233   2020-03-26     2
```

Table -2 as

```
       id     anotherdate
       1122    2020-03-30
       2233    2020-03-30
```

I want to create another column in table -2 as total in last 7 days that should calculate the sum of
table 1-no. of times  in the last 7 days from table 2 anotherdate.

Comment: Provide desired output for shown data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select count(*)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.id = t.tid and
              t2.anotherdate <= t1.date and
              t2.anotherdate > t2.date - interval 7 day
       ) as num_times
from table1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a column to your table for this derived data. Instead fetch it with a query like this.

```
SELECT t1.id, DATE(t2.anotherdate) anotherdate, SUM(t1.times) times
  FROM table_2 t2
  JOIN table_1 t1 ON t1.date >= DATE(t2.anotherdate) - INTERVAL 6 DAY
                 AND t1.date <  DATE(t2.anotherdate) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 GROUP BY t1.id, DATE(t2.anotherdate)
```

This works correctly when your date columns are actually date/time columns, or when they're just date columns.  That's the reason for using DATE().

Why do this? When you have the same data represented multiple ways in your table you have the chance of inconsistency. And SQL's made for this kind of thing.

You can create a VIEW, a virtual table, to encapsulate this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW summary_table AS
SELECT t1.id,  DATE(t2.anotherdate) anotherdate, SUM(t1.times) times
  FROM table_2 t2
  JOIN table_1 t1 ON t1.date >= DATE(t2.anotherdate) - INTERVAL 6 DAY
                 AND t1.date <  DATE(t2.anotherdate) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 GROUP BY t1.id, DATE(t2.anotherdate)
```

Then do `SELECT * FROM summary_table ORDER BY anotherdate` to get its contents.

Comment: doing in MSsql. getting error as DATE is not a function. please clarify if "SELECT t1.id, t2.date,", should it be t2.anotherdate